Taylor series applicable for Biquaternions?
I know that Taylor series can be applied for real numbers and complex numbers. I assume that this applies for Biquaternions as well, however, I'm not able to find a single source which states that. Can Biquaternions be inserted into any Taylor series?

I see no problem with that. I think that it might even be necessary to use Taylor series to define functions as $\exp$ and $\sin.$
